# Adding counts and interpreting results

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
counts = {};
$.each(answers, function(index, value) {
     counts[value] = counts[value] + 1 || 1;
});
```

It basically counts the number of occurrences in an array.  I know that the value variable can only be 1 or 2.  If I log the results to the console I see something like this

```
Object { 1=3,  2=1}
```

Now I am trying to do something with these results.  I am attempting this

```
if(counts[1]>counts[2]){
   $("#resultA").fadeIn();
} else{
   $("#resultB").fadeIn();
}
```

For some reason though, it always triggers the else clause.  What I am attempting to check is whether the count of value 1 is higher than the count of value 2.  How can I do this?

Answers array looks like this

> Object { question1=1,  question2=1,  question3=2}

Comment: Can we see your `answers` array?  I can't duplicate:  http://jsfiddle.net/a8a6o2ss/

Comment: Updated the op.  What I have seems very dodgy.  Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it does not work.  Thanks

Comment: Everything seems fine so far. Should work.

Comment: That's an object instead of an array, but I still can't duplicate:  http://jsfiddle.net/a8a6o2ss/2/